# HSQLDB: COMMIT within stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, commit, hsqldb

Within HSQLDB, I'm trying to create a stored procedure that executes a commit after having updated the database.

Something like:
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(IN p_id INTEGER)
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
  ...
  UPDATE ...
  ...
  COMMIT;
END

Creating this procedure, by means of a call to the JDBC Statement.execute() method, I get an error:
SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: COMMIT required: END

Without the COMMIT statement, the procedure is compiled correctly.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot commit the transaction inside a procedure.

You can commit after calling the procedure.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks anyway